# NodeJS file shown as non-existent while path is correct

Tags: node.js

I am checking if file exists using the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log(process.cwd());

var file="C:\\Users\\Usr1\\Documents\\Node\\Test1\\input.txt";

if(!fs.existsSync(file)) {
    console.log("File not found");
}
```

The path is correct and file does exist. If I output `file`, it also shows the correct path. I am new to NodeJS and can't figure out what is going on. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not on unix

Comment: can you show us your output of `file` and `process.cwd()`?

Comment: Please try `/` and/or read this => https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/

Comment: Did you check file permissions? Maybe the current user is not allowed to read Usr1-s documents directory.

Comment: works fine for me on linux ... maybe your path is wrong ... after your var file = xxxx   print using ...  console.log(file);   and confirm path is correct

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: use an asynchronous function to access the file like in my answer below so that you can utilize the built in `err` variable.  Console that and you can see if the error is, or isn't, related to the path being incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First.  From the `fs.existsSync()` [man pages](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) :

> Using fs.exists() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Doing so introduces a race condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file does not exist.

So, if you were too rewrite your logic, taking the recommendation into account, and adding a bit of the `path` module logic that @Hogan suggested:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require('path');

console.log(process.cwd()); // C:\Users\Usr1\Documents\Node\Test1

var file="C:\\Users\\Usr1\\Documents\\Node\\Test1\\input.txt";

fs.open(path.normalize(file), 'rx', function(err, fd){
   if (err) console.log(err); // consoling the actual error may help in troubleshooting what the issue is...  

   // do something now...
});
```

Comment: process.cwd() and `file` resolve to 
`C:\Users\Usr1\Documents\Node\Test1` and
`C:\Users\Usr1\Documents\Node\Test1\input.txt` respectively

Comment: Try replacing your file path with the relative path from your current working directory: `var file='.\input.txt'`

Comment: Also, I updated my post to add the `console.log(err)` within the `fs.open()` callback.  This will console the error for you to see.  Please paste what error is returned.